# Internal vs. external messages; Internal are sendt from L1 (some smart contract call or similar)?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

Internal vs. external messages; Internal are sendt from L1 (some smart contract call or similar) ?? And external are sendt directly to a rollup node from users…?

Question from Slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that is correct. Internal messages are smart contract calls on L1.  An L1 contract can call the rollup much like calling another contract

NB most internal messages will be smart contract calls on L1 - but every level there are three additional internal messages injected by the protocol: the `StartOfLevel`, `InfoPerLevel` & `EndOfLevel` messages